# Can't block inbound traffic on Windows 2008 Server using advanced firewall settings

Tags: windows, firewall

I have a problem with windows 2008 advanced firewall settings. When i try to block inbound traffic it's not working correctly.

For example: I made a rule for inbound traffic:

```
Local port: All ports
External port: 80
Action: block
```

If I open a webpage using internet explorer, the website is opened just fine, while it shouldn't open because I blocked the inbound traffic on port 80

Is there a reason for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the rule in the OUTBOUND traffic.
The way you have it configured its not allowing someone on your network to connect your
port 80 (web server).

So if you want to forbid browser navigation you have to block outbound traffic on port 80

PD: You should check also what are your default settings for inbound/outbound traffic. If you have both to permit by default then what is happening is what I explained before. You outbound traffic is permited so you can browse the web, and your inbound traffic is permited but you have a rules blocking port 80, so no one can telnet your machine or get information from your webserver in port 80 if available

Comment: Have you tried it? I have a rule both on inbound and outbound traffic, but i can still browse from 127.0.0.1

Comment: Well, I don't want to block outbound traffic.. I just want to block Inbound traffic. I am testing on HTTP traffic because it's easy to test using a web-browser.
@ Carlos, Well, i have set the "Remote" port = 80 for the Inbound traffic rule.. So i suppose that it means that it will block any inbound traffic with "source port = 80" which means that it will block any HTTP response.. So my web-browser should be able to send requests, but never receive anything in return.

Comment: Do you have outbound connection setting to permite by default?

Answer (score 0):

If your requests are local to the webserver (from 127.0.0.1). AFAIK no firewall rule is active at all (with windows firewall) if the request comes from the same computer. All the ports are open even if you set rules to block them,.

So to try your rule you have to make a call from a different ip. There are many online tools, for example: http://ping.eu/port-chk/

Comment: Well, the web server is not local on the machine..I try to open google.com for example and it's opening just fine.
Just a note, my goal is not to block port web-browsing.. I just need to be able to block inbound traffic on certain ports.. So i am trying on inbound traffic with source port = 80 (HTTP) first because it can easily be tested using a web-browser.

Comment: @Adel try to connect your server from http://ping.eu/port-chk/ : just put the server's ip and the port number, it will show you wether the server port is open or not to inbound traffic. With a browser it could be misleading to check for inbound traffic "only". Configuring the rule on the server should be quite strightforward.